# EntityManager does not persist

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm retrieving an entity repository from a service like this:

```
services:
    AppBundle\Repository\SecurityAwareRepository:
        abstract:  true
        calls:
            - method: setTokenStorage
              arguments:
                - "@security.token_storage"


    AppBundle\Repository\InvoiceRepository:
        parent: AppBundle\Repository\SecurityAwareRepository
        factory: ["@doctrine", getRepository]
        arguments:
            - "AppBundle:Invoice"
```

and then am processing a form in a Controller:

```
public function creditCardSaveAction(Request $request)
{
    $repo = $this->get('AppBundle\Repository\InvoiceRepository');
    /** @var \AppBundle\Entity\InvoiceAddress $latestInvoice */
    $latestInvoice = $repo->getLatestInvoice();
    if ($latestInvoice){
        $form = $this->createForm(CreditCardUpdate::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $invoiceAddress = $latestInvoice->getInvoiceAddress();
            $invoiceAddress->setCreditcardToken($form->getData()['stripeToken']);
            $invoiceAddress->setPaymentProvider($this->get('payment_provider_repository')->find(1));//hard coded to Stripe
            $repo->persist($invoiceAddress);
            $repo->flush($invoiceAddress);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('site_index');
        }else{
            return $this->redirectToRoute('creditcard_update');
        }

    }
}
```

However this does not save the 'stripeToken' field, although I can see it reaching the entity through setCreditcardToken

The persist and flush function are implemented like so:

```
class SecurityAwareRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
...    
    public function persist($entity)
    {
        $this->_em->persist($entity);
    }


    public function flush($entity)
    {
        $this->_em->flush($entity);
    }
```

Before implementing like this I simply tried

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$invoiceAddress->setCreditcardToken(...);
$em->persist($invoiceAddress);
$em->flush($invoiceAddress)
```

however this did not work either.

There is only one default EntityManager in this application

Form creation:

Controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(CreditCardUpdate::class);
        return $this->render('@AppBundle/invoice_address/credit_card_update.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
```

Twig:

```
<form action="{{  path('creditcard_save') }}" method="post" id="payment-form" class="text-center">
            {{ form_widget(form.stripeToken) }}
            {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
            <div class="form-row credit_card_background text-center">
                <div id="card-element">

                </div>

                <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-default ">Submit Payment</button>
        </form>



class CreditCardUpdate extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add( 'stripeToken', HiddenType::class );
    }
}
```

Comment: Should this code: `$form->getData()['stripeToken']` be instead: `$form->getData('stripeToken')`?

Comment: This one works as well, but doesn't save either $form->getData('credit_card_update')['stripeToken']   (credit_card_update is my form prefix

Comment: How did you create your form? in particular the `stripToken` part? Can you edit your post and show that code. Just abbreviated code only.

Comment: @AlvinBunk have added

Comment: Did you try: `$form->get('stripeToken')->getData()` as well?

Comment: @AlvinBunk this won't work as my form is submitted with credit_card_update[stripeToken]. Also, I can clearly see the token value in my debugger, but it is not persisted

Comment: @AlvinBunk I have tried it: Attempted to call an undefined method named "getStripeToken" of class "Symfony\Component\Form\Form".

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help; there must be something different in the way your forms work.

Comment: Add a dump($invoiceAddress) just before the flush to confirm that you are getting there with the expected values.

Answer (score 0):

I initially created the InvoiceAddress entity with

```
creditcardToken:
type: string
length: 200
nullable: true
```

then changed it to

```
creditcard_token:
type: string
length: 200
nullable: true
```

I ran bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle, but did not update the setter and getter.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not your answer?  For info you can use the edit button to update your question.  And do make sure you are editing the correct mapping file.  I know it sounds silly but there are a number of times where I was editing the wrong file and wondered why my changes were not taking effect.

Comment: This is the solution, sorry I didn't think of it when I wrote the question

Answer (score -1):

Try using "bind" to the form

```
$form->bind($this->getRequest());
```

Or as your code is

```
$form->bind($request);
```

Just before this line

```
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
```